# Python: Assign identical objects to same label over time

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, image-segmentation

I have the following problem. I have stacks of 2d images over time. They are already segmented. But unfortunatly in every time step the same object has a different label number. Is there maybe an easy way to assign the same label number to the objects which are the same over time?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could loop through pairs of segments, calculate the *intersection over union* value, and if it is larger than some threshold, declare them the "same" segment?

Comment: yeah i tried this, the problem here is that if there a slices where some object is not detected or if there are shifts in some slices.

Comment: This is the tracking problem. Lots and lots of literature about it. It is not easy to do it right, and don’t expect 100% correct tracking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes two objects from different frame "the same"?
- Their size?
- Relative position?
- Shape/eccentricity?
- Tilt?

You can measure these quantities per segment easily using [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) and then decide for each pair of segments if they belong to the same object or not based on a combination of these measurements.
Obviously, you can add intersection over union measure as proposed by [Andy Carlson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953186/python-assign-identical-objects-to-same-label-over-time#comment90856959_51953186).